# How solve the permission denied in databrick when using pymystem3?

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, text-processing

Due I need to process Russian data, I want to use the *pymystem3* library.

I install it successfully.
[sucess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeEs4.png)

But, when I try to use it, I can't.
[fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sncW9.png)

Comment: run cmd as administrative if your are using window otherwise root user

Comment: *Update*.

This problem occurred when I was using the library in databricks.
This is the solution:
I changed the permission of *mystem*.
%sh chmod u+x /root/.local/bin/mystem